# Как ускорить вставку из json в базу данных?

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных, json

Дана куча `json` файлов, содержащих данные. Надо поместить данные в базу `mysql`.
На `python` написал скрипт:

```
import os
import sys
import datetime

import json
from Sql  import Sql


sql = Sql(db='homestead', user='homestead', passwd='secret', host='192.168.10.10')

def getdata(path):
    fd = open(path)
    with fd as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    fd.close()

    return data

def save(data , channelname):
        i = 0
        for d in data:
        # проверку на "коллизию" убрал - думая что так быстрее будет
        #   query = "SELECT id FROM user_data where channel_name = '%s' and user_id = '%d' ;" % (channelname, d['user']['id'])  
        #   res = sql.result(query)
        #   count =  len(res)
        #   if(count == 0):

                if  'user' in d:
                    if 'id' in d['user']:
                        user_id = d['user']['id']
                    else:
                        break
                    if 'first_name' in d['user']:
                        first_name = d['user']['first_name']
                    else:
                        first_name = ' '
                    if 'last_name' in d['user']:
                        last_name = d['user']['last_name']
                    else:
                        last_name = ' '
                    if 'username' in d['user']:
                        username = d['user']['username']
                    else:
                        username = ' '
                    if 'type' in d['user']:
                        type_val = d['user']['type']
                    else:
                        type_val = ' '
                else:   
                    print('Oops')
                    break
                ctime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
                data = {'channel_name': channelname.encode("utf-8") ,
                    'user_id': user_id,
                    'user_first_name': first_name.encode("utf-8"),
                    'user_last_name': last_name.encode("utf-8"),
                    'username': username.encode("utf-8"),
                    'type': type_val.encode("utf-8") ,
                    'verified': 1 ,
                    'role': d['role'].encode("utf-8") ,
                    'phone': '', 
                    'created_at': ctime,
                    'updated_at': ctime 
                    }
                i += 1
                print(i, data)
                result = sql.insert('user_data', data)
            #       print(result)
        #query = "UPDATE saved_userdata SET parsed=1, mark='%d' WHERE path ='%s';" % (i ,'./' + channelname)
        #update=sql.update('saved_userdata',{'parsed': 1 , 'mark': i},{'path': channelname})
        #print(update)
        
        #   else:
        #       continue
        
        
try:
    print('Running script')
    query = "SELECT * FROM saved_userdata where parsed = 0"
    res = sql.result(query)
    for r in res:
        path = r['path'][2:]    
        print(path)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            data = getdata(path)
            channelname = path.split("./", 1)
            print(channelname)
            save(data, channelname[0])
        else:
            print('I cant read path ( ')
            continue    
except Exception as e:
    print("EXCEPTION :", e)
```

Он работает, но с ростом БД операция вставки данных (INSERT) стала ~ 3 секунды. Подскажите, как быстрее справиться с задачей? Есть смысл записывать данные в разные таблицы, а потом соединить воедино?

Comment: вставка зависит от количества уже имеющихся записей что ль? посмотрите не пересчитывается ли у вас индекс при каждой вставке?

Comment: может есть смысл использовать мульти инсерт вместо того что бы по одной записи вставлять ?

Comment: `insert into tab () values (), (), ()` допустим, если набор полей общий для всех json-ов

Comment: Спасибо, попробую - а есть там ограничения , у меня в json-е более 50 000 записей

Comment: размер запроса не должен превышать настройки MySQL max_allowed_packet